# kineticJS animation multiple image objects

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

The idea being that i rotate an image object then "save" this as an animation frame and do it again to build up an animation?

i only have one layer and one stage. Any help would be great.

Is it possable to save a layer as on object? and then add it back to stage?

```
var oldlayer;
oldlayer=layer;

stage.clear();

stage.add(oldlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding and removing layers to the stage is necessary. You could use `Kinetic.Node.toObject()` to act as one frame in the animation, that you can store for later use. When playing the animation, you can loop through each stored "frame" and apply them to the layer. This is kind of like thinking about an undo/redo stack.